# How can I override magento/framework/data/structure file in magento2?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I have created custom module to override this (**Magento/Framework/Data/Structure**) file.

I have tried this in `di.xml` file:

```
<preference for="Magento/Framework/Data/Structure" type="Modulename\Extendfiles\Block\Structure" />
<preference for="Magento/Framework/Data/Structure" type="Modulename\Extendfiles\Data\Structure" />
<preference for="magento/framework/Data/Structure" type="Modulename\Extendfiles\Data\Structure" />
```

But it doesn't work, can anyone help me to override this file?

Comment: Have you tried to flush magento cache?

Comment: why Magento/Framework/Data/Structure you have multiple preference for `Magento/Framework/Data/Structure` for same class

Comment: I have try one by one with preference

Comment: namespace Modulename\Extendfiles\Data;
class Structure extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Structure
{
}

Answer (score 0):

Try these CLI commands after you modify your `di.xml`:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

These commands must be executed in the root of your magento2 project.

Also choose only one preference. **(Amit Bera's advise)**

So, add this code instead of your:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Data\Structure" type="Modulename\Extendfiles\Data\Structure" />
```

Comment: namespace Modulename\Extendfiles\Data;
class Structure extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Structure
{
}

Comment: @Kyrylo, I have tried as you said but no luck